# Modifying an already answered question vs. posting a new variant of it

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I recently posted a question ([On the default/fill value for outer joins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39748976/559827)) based on a simplified example (in the spirit of a ["minimal example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  Only after reading the answers to that original question, I realized that the example I had given lent itself to solutions that I cannot readily extend to the real problem I'm working with.  IOW, without realizing it I had over-simplified the problem.

I can correct my mistake in one of two ways, but each has a significant downside:

1. change my original question; **downside:** the answers already posted would be rendered invalid;
2. post a variant of my original question that includes the complication that was left out of from it; **downside:** the second post can easily be mistaken for a duplicate of the first one, even though it definitely isn't (the answers to the first one do not apply to the second one).

I've chosen #2, since it's the easier one to revert of the two.

The second "variant" post is [On the default/fill value for *multi-key* outer joins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39751636/559827).  I'd be happy to delete it, and instead replace my original question with this variant, if that's preferable.  Please let me know.

Comment: Post a new question please.

Comment: Not an uncommon problem. many times there are numerous comments layered in also that make it better to start with new question...especially when context changes significantly

Comment: I would also provide a forward link from the old question to the new one mentioning that the new question includes the complication. The link can either be in the question, or a comment. This will allow anyone searching in the future who happens to hit the original question to go directly to the new one if the complication applies to them.

Comment: An aside to this: tag the questions with the `python` tag, I can't understand why you would want to limit your questions exposure by including only the `pandas` tag. I went ahead and added them for you, I hope you don't mind :-)

Answer (score 32):

You chose the correct option. You shouldn't make changes to a question that render existing answers obsolete. That just makes more work for everyone, and it often won't be done (or even noticed) by the people who posted those answers. It's much better to just post a variant question and point out the key differences from the original, as you have done. (Make sure that the new question is complete and can stand on its own, but it is ok to link to the original for reference.)

Comment: I would say it is not just ok, but rather necessary to link to existing questions with something like "question XXXX solves similar problem but YYYY" to avoid duplicates and not useful answers.

Answer (score 4):

I think that is a perfect thing to do.
There might be people who are looking for an answer of your over simplified problem. The existing answers are still useful.

Creating 2 separate questions also gives users looking for the same answer better understanding of their own problem.

The 2 questions are linked, and they should since they are related but differ slightly in a key way.